# Need help and need suggestion

Tags: php, magento

Can I specify payment method according to product. 
I have 2 to 3 products which paypal doesn't allow to sell so I want when buyer go to that product they can only buy through card.

Comment: You can try here: https://magento.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Hey I'll assume its Magento 2.

You could use a plugin like: [Meetanshi Payment Restrictions](https://meetanshi.com/magento-2-payment-restrictions.html?utm_source=mageplaza&utm_medium=mageplaza&utm_campaign=mageplaza-review&utm_content=Payment%20Restrictions)

This will allow you to add a custom product attribute like 'no_paypal'
And restrict payment methods based on whether this attribute is TRUE or FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

You can approach this as

1. Create an attribute for the product as `multi-select` which have the all available payment methods as option OR you can create `Yes/No` attribute and put `Yes` by default , assign `No` for the products which paypal is not allowed.
2. Now use this attribute values at checkout to hide the paypal method , you can get an idea for hiding the payment from [HERE](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/238093/magento-2-2-how-can-i-hide-or-disable-purchase-order-payment-method-for-front-e)